# Wordpress Ajax Call returns 0

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am using a plugin which (partially) stopped working. The authors are not that responsive so I started digging myself.

I've got to the part where I think that I know where the problem is: the ajax call returns 0 all the time.

If someone can help me out here?

The ajax call from the plugin:

```
        var $this = $( this ),
        $parent = $this.parents( 'li' ),
        $container = $this.closest( '.rwmb-uploaded' ),
        data = {
            action: 'rwmb_delete_file',
            _ajax_nonce: $container.data( 'delete_nonce' ),
            post_id: $( '#post_ID' ).val(),
            field_id: $container.data( 'field_id' ),
            attachment_id: $this.data( 'attachment_id' ),
            force_delete: $container.data( 'force_delete' )
        };

    $.post( ajaxurl, data, function( r )
    {
        console.log(ajaxurl);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(r);
        if ( !r.success )
        {
            alert( r.data );
            return;
        }

        $parent.addClass( 'removed' );

        // If transition events not supported
        if (
            !( 'ontransitionend' in window )
            && ( 'onwebkittransitionend' in window )
            && !( 'onotransitionend' in myDiv || navigator.appName == 'Opera' )
        )
        {
            $parent.remove();
            $container.trigger( 'update.rwmbFile' );
        }

        $( '.rwmb-uploaded' ).on( 'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend', 'li.removed', function()
        {
            $( this ).remove();
            $container.trigger( 'update.rwmbFile' );
        } );
    }, 'json' );

    return false;
```

The console.log(r) returns 0. The other two logs are filled with the correct value.

The php code for the ajax call:

```
static function add_actions()
    {
        // Add data encoding type for file uploading
        add_action( 'post_edit_form_tag', array( __CLASS__, 'post_edit_form_tag' ) );

        // Delete file via Ajax
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_rwmb_delete_file', 'wp_ajax_delete_file' );
    }

static function wp_ajax_delete_file()
    {
        $post_id       = isset( $_POST['post_id'] ) ? intval( $_POST['post_id'] ) : 0;
        $field_id      = isset( $_POST['field_id'] ) ? $_POST['field_id'] : 0;
        $attachment_id = isset( $_POST['attachment_id'] ) ? intval( $_POST['attachment_id'] ) : 0;
        $force_delete  = isset( $_POST['force_delete'] ) ? intval( $_POST['force_delete'] ) : 0;

        check_ajax_referer( "rwmb-delete-file_{$field_id}" );

        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field_id, $attachment_id );
        $ok = $force_delete ? wp_delete_attachment( $attachment_id ) : true;

        if ( $ok )
            wp_send_json_success();
        else
            wp_send_json_error( __( 'Error: Cannot delete file', 'rwmb' ) );
    }
```

But it seems that 'wp_ajax_delete_file' is never executed.

I'm looking at this code now for several days without finding a solution. Am not that skilled in ajax so I don't know the possibilities for a possible solution.

If you need something else, I'm glad to provide.

Comment: You have to use die() function at the end of ajax function to stop return 0 values.

Comment: `exit()` will also work, they are aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing this hook. This actually for non-logged in users.

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

Comment: It is only for the admin, so user who aren't logged in are not important for this part.

But I did a clean install and it worked again.

I also think that I found the source. I called the ajax from a if-loop. Something in there went wrong. If I called the ajax outside the loop, it worked, even for the calls inside. 
So now i've implemented the plugin in a different way which works for me.

But anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I did a clean install and it worked again. I also think that I found the source. I called the ajax from a if-loop. Something in there went wrong. If I called the ajax outside the loop, it worked, even for the calls inside. So now i've implemented the plugin in a different way which works for me.

Sorry I didn't post this sooner, Stackoverflow didn't let me.